# 'SqlConnection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: sql, constructor, ado.net, sqlconnection

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SHKELQIM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Menagjimi i llogarise bankare;Integrated Security=True");
```

this is the code which seems all fine in my eye as SqlConnection contains a constructor with an argument, where u can add connection string as an argument, and that's what i'm trying to do, but i'm getting this error...
"SqlConnection does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

i also confirm that i have system.data.sqlclient namespace added to the class, but this just doesn't work

anyone care to help ?

Comment: Try writing `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`. You may have a different class named `SqlConnection` in scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly that problem, i had a sqlconnection.cs class which i think i created it accidentally while trying to generate the namespace for default SqlConnection class, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably that you have another class named `SqlConnection` which does not have a one-parameter constructor.

You can confirm this by using the full name of the desired `SqlConnection` class:

```
var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
```